# Converting large matrix to dataframe

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I am sure there is a simple way to achieve this, but I cannot arrive at one based on existing questions. I have a matrix where although the View command outputs a dataframe-like feature, the structure is different. It consists of a series of lists with all the values being recognised within this as a separate numeric value.

Some example data where this data is outputted:

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:20, 500*500, replace=TRUE), ncol=500))
colsums <- as.data.frame(t(colSums(df1)))
matrix <- matrix(colsums, nrow=2)
str(matrix)
```

I have tried `as.data.frame` and `melt` functions but they do not seem to help the problem.

Comment: So what will be your desired output? a `data.frame` with 500 columns?

Comment: Please provide minimal-ier toy data than `sample(0:20, 500*500, replace=TRUE)`

Comment: In this case, a dataframe with 250 columns and 2 rows. Each column a variable. So for example, if I wanted to select the first 5 values of the top row...
matrix[1,1:5], it would output 5005, 4867, 4858, 5052, 4678 as a dataframe.

Comment: Try `df <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(matrix), nrow = 2))` maybe

Comment: @DavidArenburg that worked perfectly thank you! If you put this as an answer I can approve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to unlist the whole thing and convert to a two-rowed matrix and then convert to a `data.frame` class, e.g.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(matrix), nrow = 2))
```